# different ways in javascript of adding Event Listener to browser DOM

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

In javascript what are the different ways of adding an event listener to browser DOM?
i have tried the following code, and i was wondering if there are more ways to do this.

```
let div = document.getElementById("div");
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");

function sayHello() {
    div.innerText = "Hello World";
    console.log("awesome");
}

btn.addEventListener("click", sayHello);
```

Comment: From the documentation: [_“The `addEventListener` method is the_ recommended _way to register an event listener.”_](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). The docs also describe the inferior alternatives.

Comment: In JavaScript, there are two ways: [`addEventListener` and the `on<event name>` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick). You can further use an inline listener in the HTML but that's not "in JavaScript".

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, there are two ways for event handling.

- One of them is `addEventListener` that you used yourself.
- Another option is `onEvent`, here is an example:

**Javascript**

```
let hiButton = document.getElementById('someButton');

function sayHello() {
    console.log("Hi");
}

hiButton.onclick = sayHello();
```